# A 404 error occurs on the tour page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was looking at the tour, and the second link to the leadership code of conduct page results in a 404 error. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the information. The Leadership Code of Conduct was recently merged with the standard Code of Conduct, which explains why that link is now dead.